# KeyError in Django

Tags: python, django, keyerror

I'm creating a clone of fiverr.com as a project.

There's a header in my base.html with category titles that if I click, should filter out only the gigs in the relevant category for display.

What happens is that it always redirects to home regardless. I have done some testing and believe it should be because of the `KeyError`, and no link is passed to the function correctly.

Code below:

**views.py**

```
def category(request, link):

  categories = {
      "Graphics & Design": "GD",
      "Digital & Marketing": "DM",
      "Video & Animation": "VA",
      "Music & Audio": "MA",
      "Programming & Tech": "PT"
  }
  try:
      gigs = Gig.objects.filter(category=categories[link])
      return render(request, 'home.html', {"gigs": gigs})
  except KeyError:
      return redirect('home')
```

**models.py**

```
class Gig(models.Model):
  CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
      ("GD", "Graphics & Design"),
      ("DM", "Digital & Marketing"),
      ("VA", "Video & Animation"),
      ("MA", "Music & Audio"),
      ("PT", "Programming & Tech")
  )
  title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  category = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  price = models.IntegerField(default=6)
  photo = models.FileField(upload_to='gigs')
  status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse('my_gigs') 

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

**base.html** (where the links are - tried another way of getting the same link for Graphics & Design, but results were similar)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href='category/graphics-design'>Graphics &       Design <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'category' 'digital-marketing' %}">Digital Marketing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'category' 'video-animation' %}">Video & Animation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'category' 'music-audio' %}">Music & Audio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'category' 'programming-tech' %}">Programming & Tech</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^category/(?P<link>[\w|-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
```

Comment: could you print(link) in your script and check if you're getting the link value from the request?

Comment: hello Kunkka, thanks for your response. I did both {% print(link) %} and {{ link }} in the .html file but it could not work. Not sure if i am even printing it right. I'm still quite new to both Python and Django in general, so am figuring it out mostly on my own as I go about doing examples. Stack Overflow has been really helpful though. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The view is receiving a **slug value** in `link` parameter. So, you should redefine the `categories` dictionary:

```
def category(request, link):

  categories = {
    "graphics-design": "GD",
    "digital-marketing": "DM",
    "video-animation": "VA",
    "music-audio": "MA",
    "programming-tech": "PT"
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL that you are entering? It must be because the 'link' parameter did not find any key from your 'categories' dictionary.

Something like this(try it on your python command line):

```
>>> x = {'name': 'dean'}
>>> x['xx']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'xx'
>>>
```

By the way an advise for you when you are trying to catch. Use this syntax to see the error

```
import sys

try:
    # Code here
except:
    # Prints the error and the line that causes the error
    print ("%s - %s at line: %s" % (sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1], sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno))
```

Comment: Hi Dean thanks a lot for your suggestion. The answer above actually solved my problem just fine. I'll however try out your advice for catching errors. I'm still new in Python & Django so am learning everyday. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JimTay Glad I could help

Comment: First of all, that's ugly syntax. Second of all, you aren't providing a solution - just providing an explanation of why it's wrong